# Question on probability of two random variables for example $p(X < a, X < Y-b)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, that are independent. Suppose they have the associated distribution functions $F(x)$ and $G(y)$. Now, assume that $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed. More specifically, let $X$ be uniformly distributed in $[-\phi,\phi]$ $Y$ be uniformly distributed in interval $[0,\bar{y}]$.

Given some constants, $a,b$, how would we compute this probability?

$p(X < a, X < Y-b)$

First, I can see that this is the same as $p(X \leq \min\{a, Y-b\})$

So we would have:

$\int_x \int_y \mathbb{1}[x \leq \min\{a, y-b\}] dG(y) dF(x)$

If we assume that $\bar{y}$ is sufficiently large, how would we compute this integral?

Answer (score 1):

Let $[x<\min(a,y-b)]$ denote the function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ that takes value $1$ if $x<\min(a,y-b)$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.

Then:

$$\begin{aligned}P(X<a,X<Y-b) & =\mathbb{E}[X<\min(a,Y-b)]\\
 & =\int\int[x<\min(a,y-b)]dF(x)dG(y)\\
 & =\int F(\min(a,y-b))dG(y)\\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{a+b}F(a)dG(y)+\int_{a+b}^{\infty}F(y-b)dG(y)\\
 & =F\left(a\right)G\left(a+b\right)+\int_{a+b}^{\infty}F(y-b)dG(y)
\end{aligned}
$$

In second equality independence is used.

In third equality it is used that $F$ is a continous CDF.

---

Apply this to your mentioned special case.

Comment: Hi drhab, thank you! Can I ask why the upper bound is $a+b$?

Comment: Two cases must be discerned: $\min (a,y-b)=a$ and $\min(a,y-b)=y-b$. Equivalently the cases $y\leq a+b$ and $y>a+b$.