# How do I compute this integral of standard normally distributed variables?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, gaussian-integral

I tried to apply this approach: [Question on probability of two random variables for example $p(X < a, X < Y-b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006156/question-on-probability-of-two-random-variables-for-example-px-a-x-y-b)

to one of my problems where in my case we have Gaussian random variables and $a=0$. I ended up with the following term, but I don't know how to continue.

Denote by $Y \sim N(0,1)$ a standard Gaussian random variable with distribution function $G(y)$, and by $c$ and $b$ some constants. I want to compute the integral

$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2}erf(\frac{cy}{\sqrt2 b})dG(y) $

How do I do that? I know that $G(y)=\frac{1}{2}(1+erf(\frac{y}{\sqrt2}))$, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) is given by:
$$\text{erf} (z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{z} e^{-t^{2}} dt$$

Knowing this, it should be trivial to expand $\text{erf} \left( \frac{cy}{b \sqrt{2}}\right)$ and $\text{erf} \left( \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

Now, simply find the derivative of $G(y)$ to get $dG = G'(y) \ dy$, substitute $dG$ and $\text{erf} \left( \frac{cy}{b \sqrt{2}}\right)$ in your integral and integrate wrt $y$.

You might find it useful to note that $\text{erf}(\infty) = 1$.

> $\frac{dG}{dy} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-y^{2}/2}$

> $\int \text{erf} (z) = z \cdot \text{erf}(z) + \frac{e^{-z^{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}} + C$

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your helpful answer! Just to be sure I did understand everything correctly I am now computing: $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2}erf(\frac{cy}{\sqrt2 b})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy$?

Comment: @samabu Glad to help!